# How to check if a UILabel is vertically aligned with a ImageView

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I have a custom alert view which has a title above a image view(thin bar posing as a separator). I have centered it vertically in the .xib file, but I was wondering if there was a way to check to make 100% sure that my label is vertically aligned with the image view in my code.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very simple - compare the `center`'s `x` coordinate of each view.

```
if (yourImgV.center.x == yourLabel.center.x) {

    NSLog(@"Equal");
}
```

You could also do it like this:

```
if (yourImgV.frame.origin.x + (yourImgV.frame.size.width / 2) == yourLabel.frame.origin.x + (yourLabel.frame.size.width / 2)) {

    NSLog(@"Equal");
}
```

If the two views are subviews of different views, use the `convertPoint:` method of `UIView`.